# How to simulate a digital circuit with C++ (just input/output, no graphics)

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures, signals, simulation

I need to create a simulation of a digital circuit in C++ based on an input/output basis.

The input is given as a series of elements (or, and, nand, etc.) and as a list of connections between the pins of those elements (i.e. input pin 1 of element 1 is connected to output pin of element 2).

A source is considered an element with just an output pin, and at the end of the input file, the source is described, like is it periodic, or its custom 1 or 0 at random moments.

A probe is at the end of the circuit, and it's considered as an element with just an input pin, and checks if the value of the signal is 0 or 1 at any point in time, naturally.

So my question is, how do I create a data structure that represents a circuit? Can it be like a connected-list of elements, or should each element have pointers to other elements? And how do I transfer a signal throughout the circuit model?

Comment: If this is homework, mark it as such. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This question does not have a clear-cut answer, because it lacks a lot of important details. For example, the answers would be entirely different depending on whether or not the circuit allows outputs of elements to be fed back to them, directly or indirectly. This is more a research project than a question for a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start with a base class for your components:

   ```
   class Component
   {
       Component** inputs;
       Component** outputs;
       int numOfInputs;
       int numOfOutputs;
       virtual PropagateLogic() = 0;
   }
   ```
2. Subclass the base component for specific logic imlpementations.
3. Add code to tell a component how many inputs/outputs to expect.
4. Connect up your circuit by assigning pointers
5. ...and finally, when you want to execute your circuit, start at the inputs and walk down the chain calling propagate.

Comment: I'd suggest using a ``std::vector<Component*>`` instead of the combination of ``Component**`` and ``int``. That way, you do not need to manually manage the arrays, which is both cumbersome and dangerous (error-prone).

Comment: Yup, fair point. There are all sorts of ways you could simplify / complicate / improve my suggestion, I just wanted to give a very basic example..

Comment: Could you maybe offer an example for the propagate method? how would I implement it to go through the whole structure?

Answer (score 2):

What you've described is a programming paradigm called "[Flow-Based Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming)".

If you're interested, I've developed an C++ object-oriented flow-based programming library called [DSPatch](http://www.flowbasedprogramming.com) (or "dispatch"). The generic object-oriented API allows you to create and route almost any type of process chain imaginable, from basic logic circuits to full-blown electronics simulation. Its fast, very easy-to-use, and free for personal / proprietary use.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should look for a graph like structure. You could add a field specifying if its active/turned on or not and relaying all incoming data to active neighbouring nodes. But this might go a bit more in the AN direction.

Comment: In fact, you could probably do something with the prefuse library. It is a Java library, but I converted it to Objective-C, it took a bit of time, but it was simple enough.

Comment: How can I create a graph-like structure? Could I use the Composite software design pattern with Digital Elements as Leaves? How can I relay the data to neighbouring nodes? :)

Comment: I haven't done anything like this, but I can imagine a node accepting an array of inputs, and, dependent on its ability to relay information c.q. being on or off, which you could respresent with a bool, sending information to its neighbours. There are many different ways to approach this. I can imagine some sort of publish/subscribe mechanism in which you subscribe a new node to a certain node. When the publishing nodes sends some information an event is triggered in the subscriber on which you can take further action. You could look for the publish/subscribe or the observer oattern.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely store it in a graph.

For simple simulation storing the connection should be enough, with a data flow simulation.

If you doing something more complex, for example want to be able to detect [hazards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_%28logic%29), you have to store the delays of the basic building blocks and lengths of the wires. Then you can build a time-based system where each change on wires triggers at specific (maybe not-totally deterministic) time on the output wires of the devices.